Internal server error: localStorage is not defined - Angular 17
I am configuring the UserStorageService with all the necessary methods for log in and sign out of the application, but when I execute it it gives me that error
this is my code
This is the storage service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const TOKEN = 'ecom-token'
const USER = 'ecom-user'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserStorageService {

  constructor() { }

  public saveToken(token: string): void{
    window.localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN);
    window.localStorage.setItem(TOKEN,token);
  }

  public saveUser(user): void{
    window.localStorage.removeItem(USER);
    window.localStorage.setItem(USER, JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  static getToken(): string{
    return localStorage.getItem(TOKEN);
  }

  static getUser(): any{
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(USER));
  }

  static getUserId(): string{
    const user = this.getUser();
    if(user == null){
      return '';
    }
    return user.userId;
  }

  static getUserRole(): string{
    const user = this.getUser();
    if(user == null){
      return '';
    }
    return user.role;
  }

  static isAdminLoggedIn(): boolean{
    if(this.getToken === null){
      return false;
    }
    const role: string = this.getUserRole();
    return role == 'ADMIN';
  }

  static isCustomerLoggedIn(): boolean{
    if(this.getToken === null){
      return false;
    }
    const role: string = this.getUserRole();
    return role == 'CUSTOMER';
  }

  static signOut(): void{
    window.localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN);
    window.localStorage.removeItem(USER);
  }

}

this is the app component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserStorageService } from './services/storage/user-storage.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'e-commerce';

  isCotumerLoggedIn : boolean = UserStorageService.isCustomerLoggedIn();
  isAdminLoggedIn : boolean = UserStorageService.isAdminLoggedIn();

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      this.isCotumerLoggedIn = UserStorageService.isCustomerLoggedIn();
      this.isAdminLoggedIn = UserStorageService.isAdminLoggedIn();
    })
  }


  logout(){
    UserStorageService.signOut();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('login')
  }



}


I have tried verifying the imports and so on but nothing has helped me, I re-wrote the code in case I wrote wrong but nothing is solved

I think you might have SSR enabled in your application, so you are getting the errors, when the content renders on the server.
Make the logic happen only when it's the browser, we can use isPlatformBrowser and solve it, for the static method you could use the TypeScript ?. safe access to ensure you do not get any errors:
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

const TOKEN = 'ecom-token'
const USER = 'ecom-user'

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserStorageService {
    isBrowser: boolean;

    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object) {
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    }

    public saveToken(token: string): void {
        if (this.isBrowser) {
            window.localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN);
            window.localStorage.setItem(TOKEN, token);
        }
    }

    public saveUser(user): void {
        if (this.isBrowser) {
            window.localStorage.removeItem(USER);
            window.localStorage.setItem(USER, JSON.stringify(user));
        }
    }

    static getToken(): string {
        return localStorage ? localStorage.getItem(TOKEN) : '';
    }

    static getUser(): any {
        return localStorage ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(USER)) : '';
    }

    static getUserId(): string {
        const user = this.getUser();
        if (user == null) {
            return '';
        }
        return user.userId;
    }

    static getUserRole(): string {
        const user = this.getUser();
        if (user == null) {
            return '';
        }
        return user.role;
    }

    static isAdminLoggedIn(): boolean {
        if (this.getToken === null) {
            return false;
        }
        const role: string = this.getUserRole();
        return role == 'ADMIN';
    }

    static isCustomerLoggedIn(): boolean {
        if (this.getToken === null) {
            return false;
        }
        const role: string = this.getUserRole();
        return role == 'CUSTOMER';
    }

    static signOut(): void {
        if (window?.localStorage) {
            window.localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(USER);
        }
    }
}

It is pointless to use local storage on the server. It's a browser-only functionality, because document and window only exist on the browser.

It's a small stylistic point, but alongside the spelling corrections I have mentioned, do you think you could reduce your usage exclamation marks? They are not suitable for technical writing. They are intended generally to indicate surprise or humour, and should in any piece of writing be used sparingly. They are not a replacement for a full stop (to finish a sentence) or a colon (to indicate that the sentence is illustrated by immediately following material, such as code).

Exclamation marks (sometimes known as "bangs") are more suited to informal writing that you might use on social media. There is a community preference for technical writing here, which we regard more like documentation than a forum.
